# Difference in length between string and character array in c?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm a beginner with C.

I'm taking a string from the user. Then I am storing the letters of the string, one by one, into a character array.

The code compiles fine.

However, when I do a strlen function on both of them, the result doesn't match.

if
The length of the string, for example is 9.

then
The length of the character array comes out to 11.

from what I understand, strings in C has a terminating null byte. So if anything, shouldn't strlen of a string be Longer than the character array made from the same string?
what is causing the difference?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ( int argc, string argv[])

{   
 string plaintext = get_string("Enter plaintext:  ");
    
    printf ("length of plaintext is : %lu", strlen(plaintext));
    
printf("\n");

    
    char newstring [(strlen(plaintext))] ; 
    
    for (int i = 0, m = strlen (plaintext); i < m ; i++)
    {
        newstring[i] = plaintext[i];
        
        printf("%c  ", plaintext[i]);
        
        printf("\n");
        
    }
    
printf("length of newstring is : %lu", strlen(newstring));

printf("\n");

printf("%s", newstring);

printf ("\n");

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The length of a nul-terminated string is determined by where the first nul (0-byte) is. It doesn't look like you're copying the terminating nul from the source string.

Comment: Thanks - So the strlen (string) is stopping at the null character but the strlen(character array) is not? Just wanna make sure I understand.

Comment: How is this code compiling? To my knowledge, C does not have a `string` type, or a function named `get_string` in its standard library.

Comment: @LevM. I’m using some libraries that provide these functions.

Comment: @nicotinefull Exactly. `strlen(newstring)` will then stop at some random byte in memory that'll happen to be nul.

Comment: Then you need to make this clear in your question. There is no way to know what your code is doing if it uses data types or functions we know nothing about!

Comment: @LevM. I see - I wasn’t aware of that ... I thought maybe there was some default properties/behaviors of data types that’s causing this difference. Would you say if all other things were standard the length of a string and a character array should be the same?

Comment: @nicotinefull See the full explanation in my answer, but the short version is - there are not "strings" in C.

Answer (score 2):

A *string* is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator.  The string `"hello"` is represented as the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.  C does not have a true string type - the `string` typedef provided by the CS50 and similar libraries is an alias for the type `char *`, which is *not a string*.  Due to the decay rule, most of the time when we’re dealing with strings we’re dealing with expressions of type `char *`, but those expressions are not strings in and of themselves.

Strings are stored in arrays of character type (`char` for ASCII, EBCDIC, UTF-8, etc., or `wchar_t` for "wide" encodings).  To store an N-character string, the array must be *at least* N+1 elements wide to account for the terminator.  The problem in your code is that you are not properly terminating `newstring`, so `strlen` goes past the end of it and keeps counting until it sees a 0-valued byte.  You must define `newstring` as

```
char newstring[ strlen( plaintext ) + 1 ];
```

In your loop, you must iterate from 0 to `m+1` to copy the string terminator from `plaintext` to `newstring`.  Alternately, you could just use `strcpy`.

`strlen` gives you the number of characters in the string up to *but not including* the terminator - `strlen( "hello" )` will return 5, but the array that stores `"hello"` must be at least 6 elements wide.  That calculation gets a bit more complicated for variable-length encodings like UTF-8, where a single character may require more than one byte to store.  I have no experience dealing with extended UTF-8 characters in C, so I won’t say more about it except that it’s something to be aware of.

Another thing to be aware of is that arrays in C don’t automatically grow or shrink as you write to them - an array’s size is fixed throughout its lifetime, so if you define an array to store 10 characters and you try to write 100 characters to it, those extra 90 characters will get written to the memory following the array, which may result in corrupted data, a runtime error, or something else.  C doesn’t do bounds checking on array access, so it’s up to you to make sure you don’t overflow a buffer (this is true for all array types, not just character arrays).

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to understand that C does not have strings.

There is no type `string` in the language.

What C considers to be "strings" are actually always arrays of type `char` that are expected to be null-terminated, meaning that there will be a '\0' char somewhere in the array.

All functions that operate on strings, such as 'strlen', 'strcpy' and 'strcmp', rely on this null character to know when to stop scanning the array.

The reason for this is that C arrays do not contain information about their size.

So, if you do not have the null character, any `str` function will run until it finds one or tries to access memory your program is not allowed to access.

This is why some of these functions are considered unsafe - they can result in undefined behavior and allow exploits.

Another important thing to know is that C does not initialize local variables, so in your code `newstring` will have unpredictable values.

That means unless you put a null character in there explicitly, it won't have one!

Comment: i see -- I think that unpredictability  (as an example) if I enterd "ba ba ba" as plaintext, the newstring would print out something like "ba ba ba@"  ... how would I go about accepting a string (of unknown length)  from users  modifying a character array (for example to shift each letter by a value of 7)? if I do a loop on the string and modify each character -- how do I then feed it output character by character to a global - scope variable? I understand this is a broader/different question, just point me to what topic I should look into please  -- thanks!

Comment: This is several topics. First, you need to learn how to read a single character. Then, if you want to store unlimited number of them, you need to learn about dynamic memory allocation. Finally, you need to figure out an algorithm like read -> check if not end of input -> shift value -> store in array -> check if array full -> increase size of array -> repeat. For this specific exorcise though, you can probably just make sure you have one extra space in the array and put the null character there yourself.

Comment: "C does not have strings" --> The spec of the C library defines "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  So C does have a well defined  _string_ even if it is not a type.

Comment: "C arrays do not contain information about their size." --> Hmmm,  `char a[5]; printf("%zu\n", sizeof a);` certainly prints the size of the array.

Comment: "C does not initialize variables" --> true for variable in a function.  False for global variables.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica good catch on the variable initialization, but I consider the other two comments a matter of semantics, and the OP is just learning. Consider passing `a` from your example to a function, would `sizeof` still work?

Comment: When array `a` is passed to function, it is converted to pointer of the first element. Function `bar(a)` receives that pointer.  Within the function, `sizeof(some pointer)` still _works_ to supply the size of a pointer. With `foo(char (*a)[42]); char array[42];  foo(&array)`, `sizeof(*a)` within the function works to supply the expected size of 42.  With VLA notation, even more flexible ways are possible to pass array size info to a function.  I

Answer (score -2):

char arrays have a terminating character "\0"

Comment: A *string* has a terminating null character, because C 2018 7.1.1 1 specifies “A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.” An *array of `char`* may or may not have a zero-valued element in it, because an array of `char` is simply a contiguous range of storage that can hold `char` values. It can be used for arbitrary arithmetic purposes, not just character strings, and it can hold characters that are not terminated by a null character.